# GUI ISO to USB tools in Debian or something which is available at github or elsewhere

Tags: debian, usb, iso

Are there any GUI ISO to USB tools in Debian?

I mean a way in which I could copy the .iso files to a USB/pen-drive. While I know the dd way intimately, am looking for a tool which a normal/lay user could use via a GUI. I know brasero is used for doing the same to a DVD and would be seeing if brasero can do this for a USB (although know it doesn't), but am looking to see if there is a specialist tool for the job.

If somebody knows a git repo. or something somewhere which is not yet in Debian please point out so I could try the same on my system and also file an RFP for the same in Debian. I am open to compile and build whatever libraries or things are needed to have such a tool in Debian.

Unetbootin is not the answer. See https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb for more.

Comment: Explaining your (failed) exploits in web-browsing should never be part of a question without chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) if that sounds unfamiliar). Neither is including Update (this site has edit history, if someone really needs to know about previous states) And if you wouldn't be looking forward to answers to your post, I hope you wouldn't be posting in the first place. *Don't obscure your post by including question irrelevant things.*

Comment: usb-creator-gtk is a tool available for Ubuntu. Pls check this will help

Answer (score 0):

Try UNetbootin.  www.unetbootin.sourceforge.net

Comment: sorry, that is not the answer, have edited the answer to tell/share why, thank you for attempting though.